# Anchor Scroll not working

Tags: anchor

I have a button at the top of the page:(Button-A)

```
 <div class="menu-btn-right loginandadd" >
  <a href="#" id="A" class="some_class" title="something"</a>
 </div>
```

Then I have another button half way through the page (Button-A is not visible anymore):(Button-B)

```
<a id="B"><img class="start1addproductbutton" src="#" alt="empty" width="1" height="1" /> 
</a>
```

Also, I have the following script:

```
<script>// 
<![CDATA[ jQuery("#B").click(function(){
     jQuery("#A").trigger('click');            
         return false;       });
// ]]></script>
```

In this current setting, when the Button-B is clicked, Button-A is clicked automatically.However since the Button-B is located in the middle and Button-A is not visible, when the Button-B is clicked, users do not know that Button-A is clicked unless they manually scroll to the top.

I tried to add an anchor so that when the button-B is clicked, the page is scrolled to the top and users can see that Button-A is automatically clicked.

However in my test due to the javascript, the anchor tag is not working.
What can I do so that when Button-B is clicked, the page is scrolled to the top and Button-A is still automatically clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code which scrolls to element A manually, instead of triggering the click event of that element.

```
<script>
 jQuery("#B").click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#A").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
 });
</script>
```